# How to make a d3 plugin?

Tags: plugins, d3.js

I would like to make a simple d3 plugin but can't find information on how to do it.

It needs to be very simple:

```
s.append('text').text("Some Text").editable();
```

should just translate to

```
s.append('text').text("Some Text").attr('data-editable', true);
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Wow, there is a major lack of documentation for this. jQuery has spoiled me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Had to go digging through the source but got it finally.

```
(function() {
  d3.selection.prototype.editable = function() {
    return this.attr('data-editable', true);
  };
})();
```

[Jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/ifayel/1/)

also note that if you also want the plugin to apply after you `.enter()` you need to assign the `d3.selection.enter.prototype`.

If (as in my case) you want your plugin available in both scenarios:

```
(function() {
    d3.selection.prototype.editable = d3.selection.enter.prototype.editable = function() {
        return this.attr('data-editable', true);
      };
})();
```

Comment: Nice, much better than what I was trying to hack together.

Comment: @Wex - good point http://jsbin.com/ifayel/5/edit seems like in that case you would want to iterate.

Comment: @Wex Old question, I know. But the answer is "Yes". Here is an example based on the code given by OP: http://jsbin.com/yuvadeviro/2

Answer (score 15):

Mike Bostock wrote Towards Reusable Charts http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

I followed this pattern to make an extremely simple example d3 plugin, please see this block: http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5073718 (and the source gist: https://gist.github.com/cpbotha/5073718).

According to Mike Bostock, reusable charts should be implemented as "closures with getter-setter methods". I did exactly that in my example above.

The answer of @Wex follows this pattern too, except that it doesn't demonstrate the closure idea, as the original question did not specify requiring any properties.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've seen it documented:

```
function editable() {
    d3.select(this).attr("data-editable", true);
}
```

Followed by:

```
s.append('text').text("Some Text").call(editable);
```

or

```
d3.selectAll("text").each(editable);
```

Although I like George's solution better.

Comment: I think that to the extent that D3 offers a "standard" plugin approach, it's through `.call()`. This isn't quite as elegant as extending the prototype, but it avoids the hassles @George Mauer notes