# Retrieve Data Bindings d3

Tags: javascript, plugins, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a d3 plugin ala this stackoverflow question:

[How to make a d3 plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983864/how-to-make-a-d3-plugin)

But within his shown example

```
(function() {
    d3.selection.prototype.editable = d3.selection.enter.prototype.editable = function() {
        return this.attr('data-editable', true);
      };
})();
```

I don't see how he can actually retrieve the data associated with the selection.  Is this something that can even be retrieved with this extension of d3.selection?  I mucked through the d3 source a little bit but found myself far more confused than before.

Can someone who has written a d3 extension/plugin guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, the object that `this` refers to is (usually, and in your example code above) determined by the object which calls the function where `this` appears.

Hence the line `return this.attr('data-editable', true);` will return the exact same d3 selection object that calls `editable`.

So you will get back the normal old d3 selection object, just as you would in the ordinary d3 method chaining pattern.  Once you have that, getting the data is [just a matter of looking up the API for the d3 selection object.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)

If you are interested specifically in how to get the data back, take a look at the data method.  From the link above, when that method is called with no arguments:

> If values is not specified, then this method returns the array of data
>   for the first group in the selection. The length of the returned array
>   will match the length of the first group, and the index of each datum
>   in the returned array will match the corresponding index in the
>   selection. If some of the elements in the selection are null, or if
>   they have no associated data, then the corresponding element in the
>   array will be undefined.